# How to use external Canvas xaml in resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017

I'm creating a wpf application in Visual Studio 2017.

I have some icons as separate files in xaml format. They look something like this:

```
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="appbar_connect" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
    <Path Width="36.7542" Height="36.7542" Canvas.Left="19.6229" Canvas.Top="19.6229" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 25.7639,28.0031L 20.0866,22.3258C 19.4683,21.7075 19.4683,20.705 20.0866,20.0866C 20.705,19.4683 21.7075,19.4683 22.3258,20.0867L 28.0031,25.7639C 32.3443,22.5092 38.5302,22.856 42.4783,26.8042L 26.8041,42.4784C 22.856,38.5302 22.5092,32.3443 25.7639,28.0031 Z M 49.1958,33.5217C 53.144,37.4699 53.4908,43.6557 50.2361,47.9969L 55.9133,53.6742C 56.5317,54.2925 56.5317,55.295 55.9133,55.9134C 55.295,56.5317 54.2925,56.5317 53.6742,55.9134L 47.9969,50.2361C 43.6557,53.4908 37.4698,53.1441 33.5216,49.1959L 36.8804,45.8371L 34.0814,43.0381C 33.1539,42.1107 33.1539,40.6069 34.0814,39.6794C 35.0089,38.7519 36.5127,38.7519 37.4402,39.6794L 40.2392,42.4784L 42.4783,40.2392L 39.6794,37.4402C 38.7519,36.5127 38.7519,35.009 39.6794,34.0815C 40.6069,33.154 42.1106,33.154 43.0381,34.0815L 45.8371,36.8804L 49.1958,33.5217 Z "/>
</Canvas>
```

I notice they don't have an x:Key just an x:Name

I have got them to work by copying & pasting the code into my resource library and adding an x:Key to reference them using

```
<Viewbox>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource appbar_connect}" />
</Viewbox>
```

in my main window xaml.

But is there any way to just drop them into a folder and reference them by the name without having to open each one and copy & paste and add x:Tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you was asking for but to manage my icons I have a ressourceDictonary containing all the icons as style and i select them using their x:Key like so:

```
</ResourceDictionary>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}" x:Key="Close">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="M 15.125 12.28125 [...]Z"/>
  </Style>
  [...]
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}" x:Key="Reload">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="M 20 4 C 15.054688 4 11 [...]Z"/>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Usage:

```
<Button>
   <Viewbox Height="25">
       <Path Fill="{StaticResource stdBackGround}" Style="{StaticResource Close}"/>
   </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be a slightly nicer way of doing things than I currently am, and lets you override the colour too. Still lots of copy & pasting code though.

Comment: sorry i did a mistake here i updated my response! Of cause you do not copy the data but only use the style